# Calculating autocorrelation of impulse responsed signal

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose that the autocorrelation function of a random signal $X(t)$ is given by
$$R_{XX}(\tau)=e^{-|\tau|}$$

and $X(t)$ was passed to the input of an impulse response function $h$ defined as $h(t)=e^{-t}$ if $t>0$, and $0$ otherwise.
Now I want to calculate the autocorrelation function of the output $Y(t)=h(t) * x(t)$.

I tried calculating $Y(t)$ first:
$$Y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(\tau)x(t-\tau)d\tau=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\tau}x(t-\tau)d\tau$$
but got stuck from here.

The second approach I've tried was implying Fourier Transform on $R_{XX}(\tau)$ and $h(t)$:

$$|X(w)|^2 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|t|}e^{-jwt}dt=\frac{2}{w^2+1}, H(w)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(jw+1)t}dt=\frac{1}{jw+1}$$
and $|Y(w)|^2=|H(w)|^2|X(w)|^2=\frac{1}{w^2+1}\cdot\frac{2}{w^2+1}=\frac{2}{(w^2+1)^2}$, but I couldn't calculate the inverse Fourier transformation of $\frac{2}{(w^2+1)^2}$.

I think there should be an easy idea to solve this problem. How can I solve this?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(\omega)=\frac2{(\omega^2+1)^2}$.  The inverse Fourier Transform, $f$, of $F$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
f(t)&=\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{F\}(t)\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac2{(\omega^2+1)^2}e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

Note that we can differentiate $f$ twice by differentiating under the integral to find

$$\begin{align}f''(t)&=-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2\omega^2}{(\omega^2+1)^2}e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\underbrace{-\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{\omega^2+1}e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega}_{=-e^{-|t|}}+\underbrace{\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac2{(\omega^2+1)^2}e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega}_{=f(t)}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that $f''(t)-f(t)=-e^{-|t|}$ with $f(0)=1/2$ and $f'(0)=0$.  Now, solving the ODE subject to the initial conditions yields

$$f(t)=\frac12 (1+|t|)e^{-|t|}$$

---

Alternatively, we can use contour integration to evaluate the Fourier Transform.  Note that there are poles at $\pm i$.  Therefore, we have for $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
f(t) &= i\text{Res}\left(\frac{2e^{i\omega t}}{(\omega^2+1)^2}, \omega=i\right)\\\\
&=i \lim_{\omega \to i}\frac{d}{d\omega}\left(\frac{2e^{i\omega t}}{(\omega+i)^2}\right)\\\\
&=i\left(\frac{i2t e^{-t}}{-4}-\frac{4e^{-t}}{-8i}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12(t+1)e^{-t}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $f(t)$ is even, we have

$$f(t)=\frac12 (1+|t|)e^{-|t|}$$

as expected!